# Android: custom AlertDialog, viewPager : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: android

Android 4.3.

My custom dialogFragment:

```
public class IntroductoryTourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
private int totalPagesCount;
private Activity activity;

private static final String TAG = IntroductoryTourDialogFragment.class.getName();

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.introductory_tour_layout, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setView(view);
    setCancelable(false);
    init(view);
    return builder.create();
}

private void init(View view) {
    totalPagesCount = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.introductory_tour_images_names).length;
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.introductory_tour_viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new IntroductoryTourPageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        String introductory_tour_images_name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.introductory_tour_images_names)[position];
        args.putString(IntroductoryTourPageFragment.TOUR_PAGE_NAME, introductory_tour_images_name);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return totalPagesCount;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}
}
```

My custom xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/introductory_tour_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when try run this dialog fragment I get error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e026e
    (com.my_project:id/introductory_tour_viewPager)
    for fragment IntroductoryTourPageFragment{427e2d10 #2 id=0x7f0e026e android:switcher:2131624558:0}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
```

Comment: Try using viewapger width android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: It's not help. Same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your dialog `View` is not created properly. Before creating `View`, you are trying to initialize `ViewPager` and set `SectionsPagerAdapter` to `ViewPager`.

**SOLUTION:**

**1.** First, remove overridden method `onCreateDialog()`.

**2.** Override `onCreateView()` and inflate your layout `introductory_tour_layout` from here:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.introductory_tour_layout, container);

        return view;
    }
```

**3.** When view created successfully, initialize your `ViewPager` set `SectionsPagerAdapter` to `ViewPager`. To do this call method `init(view)` From `onViewCreated()`:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        init(view);
    }
```

**4.** When creating instance of `SectionsPagerAdapter` use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

**Here is the working code:**

```
public class IntroductoryTourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private int totalPagesCount;
    private Activity activity;

    private static final String TAG = IntroductoryTourDialogFragment.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.introductory_tour_layout, container);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        init(view);
    }

    private void init(View view) {
        totalPagesCount = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.introductory_tour_images_names).length;
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.introductory_tour_viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = new IntroductoryTourPageFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            String introductory_tour_images_name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.introductory_tour_images_names)[position];
            args.putString(IntroductoryTourPageFragment.TOUR_PAGE_NAME, introductory_tour_images_name);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return totalPagesCount;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

**To show `IntroductoryTourDialogFragment` , use below code in your `Activity`:**

```
IntroductoryTourDialogFragment introductoryTourDialogFragment = new IntroductoryTourDialogFragment();
introductoryTourDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), introductoryTourDialogFragment.getTag());
```

**This also work (without `onViewCreated()`):**

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.introductory_tour_layout, null);
        init(view);

        return view;
    }
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: @Alexei i think you don't need to create builder instance. Can you please try it without >>> AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setView(view);
        setCancelable(false);

Comment: Yes you are right. It's work without "AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity); builder.setView(view);"